# Use of unresolved identifier 'requestIPViewController' , Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, identifier

[image]
it shows me there are some problems on the code

So How Can I fix that?

```
self.presentViewController[requestIPViewController, animated:YES, completion:nil];

}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
```

Comment: Where have you declared requestIPViewController and what is info? Please check and tell the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is in swift 2.3 then it should be like that

```
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And you must type cast it like it

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
            as! UIImage
```

And swift 3.0 it looks like that

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And detegate method looks like that

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as String) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
            as! UIImage
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: then its Swift 3.0 +

Comment: It's same thing nothing change

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of it ?

Comment: I think You havent declared requestIPViewController , first error is because of this, please check